# Error when install any packages on R after installing new OS

Tags: r

I tried to install any package on R but I always got an error like shown on picture below:

**Error for `xlsx` package:**

[image]

**Error for `quadprog` package:**

[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?

Below is my R.Version() output:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "3.1"

$year
[1] "2016"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "21"

$`svn rev`
[1] "70800"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"

$nickname
[1] "Bug in Your Hair"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after I installed gcc

Answer (score 0):

It appears likely that you need to install the gfortan library, which you can install using the terminal command `sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.6` and the other error can be solved by installing [java](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml).

Comment: I had Java installed on my laptop. Like now, I try to install dplyr, I still get error message.